# Error in python script : Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I was writing a script to create skeletons of images (in a video) of worms, to measure the length of said skeletons.
The script was working fine until some videos stopped the program with the following error message:

> "Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)"

I have no idea, what happened since it was working fine for every other video F fed the program with. The only difference was in video length. Videos resulting in this error message were 2 mins long while other around 1 min. Still, the error message only occurd for some videos and not all and when it appeared, it was not consistant at a specific frame but rather always at a different one.

I tried to get more information about the error using faulthandler.

The message I recieved from was:

```
Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374

Thread 0x00001e78 (most recent call first):   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\_parsing.py",
line 60 in run   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\threading.py", line 932
in _bootstrap_inner   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\threading.py", line 890
in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00003918 (most recent call first):   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
line 2698 in new   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
line 2784 in frombuffer   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
line 2849 in fromarray   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py",
line 835 in ndarray_to_pil   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillowmulti.py",
line 347 in converToPIL   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillowmulti.py",
line 159 in add_image   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillowmulti.py",
line 116 in _append_data   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\format.py",
line 502 in append_data   File
"C:/Users/Dennis/Documents/PhD/Python/WormRuler/worm_ruler_V3.1.py",
line 281 in skeletonize   File
"C:/Users/Dennis/Documents/PhD/Python/WormRuler/worm_ruler_V3.1.py",
line 339 in skeletonization   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1892 in __call__   File
"C:\Users\Dennis\anaconda3\envs\WormRuler\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1429 in mainloop   File
"C:/Users/Dennis/Documents/PhD/Python/WormRuler/worm_ruler_V3.1.py",
line 645 in <module>

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
```

Maybe a snippet of the code is helpful:

```py
import skan
import os
import imageio
from skimage.morphology import thin
from skimage.util import img_as_bool
from skimage import color
from fil_finder import FilFinder2D
import astropy.units as u
import warnings

# Ignore filfinder warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*No beam width given.*', )
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*Graph pruning reached max iterations.*', )

def skeletonize():
    # open vid
    video_root = "C:/Users/Dennis/Desktop/test_marius/"
    folders = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(video_root):
        for folder in d:
            folders.append(folder)
    for folder in folders:
        video_paths = []
        for r, d, f in os.walk(str(video_root) + "/" + str(folder)):
            for file in f:
                if "_bw.gif" in file:
                    video_paths.append(os.path.join(r, file))

        for v_path in video_paths:
            vid = imageio.get_reader(v_path, 'ffmpeg')
            worm_lengths = []
            for num, frame in enumerate(vid):
                try:
                    img = color.rgb2gray(frame)
                    binary = img_as_bool(img)
                    # perform skeletonization
                    skel = thin(binary)
                    fil = FilFinder2D(skel, distance=250 * u.pc, mask=skel)
                    fil.medskel(verbose=False)
                    fil.analyze_skeletons(branch_thresh=400 * u.pix, skel_thresh=10 * u.pix, prune_criteria='length')
                    skel_fil = fil.skeleton_longpath
                    # checks if any true values in numpy array of skeleton
                    if skel.any():
                        paths = skan.Skeleton(skel_fil, keep_images=False)
                        pathlengths = paths.path_lengths()
                        pathlengths.sort()
                        worm_lengths.append(pathlengths[0])
                    else:
                        worm_lengths.append(None)
                except:
                    worm_lengths.append(None)

skeletonize()
```

can be used to reproduce the error message. Videos producing the error can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GoqTr7kMT-yzobgbkWU2zvj_7d0asdZe/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: buddy try to completely uninstall anaconda and reinstall it. Then try making a new virtual environment if you have one ,to resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried it already. Also send the code to a colleague who tested it on his system.

Comment: Exception code 0xc0000374 means you're facing heap corruption. So it has something to do with memory management in the Windows operating system. I wouldn't know where to start debugging this kind of error. You might simply have run out of available RAM. You can use the Windows Resource Monitor to spot such a memory leak. But that's a just a guess.

Comment: See [these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Process%20finished%20with%20exit%20code%201073740940%20).

Comment: @bad_coder Thank you. I added a code that produces the error message along with example videos to test it. Looking through the other threads, none were helpful to solve my problem, thats why I created a new one.

Comment: @bad_coder Yes, I tried to isolate the error more.

Comment: @dvettkoe looks good now.